# Image upload and view with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-uploading

Please can someone explains me how to upload images and view them with codeigniter. I tried many ways but none of them work for me. Any help would be higly appreciated

Comment: read this [link](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html), and show your code please

Comment: Mr. Molagbal this is the code  http://www.codexworld.com/codeigniter-upload-multiple-files-images/  that  I tried. It works well. But I want to extend this to upload images at two places of the same page and view them. For an exmple it is like we upload our profile picture and cover photo to the face book.

Comment: But that u haven't explained that in your question...can you show me what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Should refer CodeIgniter user guide. [File Upload in Codeigniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html).

Firstly, you’ll need to create a destination folder where you want your images to get uploaded.

So, Create a folder named “uploads” at the root of your CodeIgniter(CI) installation.

Now create two view **files file_view.php** and upload_success.php in a views folder of CodeIgniter. The first file will display a complete form that contains upload field and the second file is to display the message “successfully uploaded”.

> File uploads require a multipart form

Here I give you an example of it, hope it helps.

HTML code.

```
<?php echo $error;?>
<!-- Error Message will show up here -->
<?php echo form_open_multipart( 'upload_controller/do_upload');?>
<?php echo "<input type='file' name='userfile' size='20' />"; ?>
<?php echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='upload' /> ";?>
<?php echo "</form>"?>
```

Controller code:

```
            <?php
        if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
            exit('No direct script access allowed');
        class Upload_Controller extends CI_Controller
        {
            public function __construct()
            {
                parent::__construct();
            }
            public function file_view()
            {
                $this->load->view('file_view', array(
                    'error' => ' '
                ));
            }
            public function do_upload()
            {
                $config = array(
                    'upload_path' => "./uploads/",
                    'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf",
                    'overwrite' => TRUE,
                    'max_size' => "2048000", // Can be set to particular file size , here it is 2 MB(2048 Kb)
                    'max_height' => "768",
                    'max_width' => "1024"
                );
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                if ($this->upload->do_upload()) {
                    $data = array(
                        'upload_data' => $this->upload->data()
                    );
                    $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
                } else {
                    $error = array(
                        'error' => $this->upload->display_errors()
                    );
                    $this->load->view('file_view', $error);
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Your View:

```
        <h3>Your file was successfully uploaded!</h3>
    <!-- Uploaded file specification will show up here -->
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($upload_data as $item => $value):?>
            <li>
                <?php echo $item;?>:
                    <?php echo $value;?>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <p>
        <?php echo anchor('upload_controller/file_view', 'Upload Another File!'); ?>
    </p>
```

For Retrieving image:

First of all, you need to save the image URL in the database.

```
$this->model->insert_data($upoad_data['file_name'], $upoad_data['full_path']);

$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

$this->load->view('your_view', $data);
```

Now in View use $data.

```
<image src="<?php you should use that data to view image. >">
```

I hope now it's clear to you that how to display image after uploading.

Comment: Glad that it works for you. Keep Coding.

Comment: Mr.Ankith It worked well..Please explain me how to retrieve the image at place that we upload,

Comment: For retrieve image, first of all, you should save that image URL in the database. And then fetch it from database.

Comment: Can you please share the code? It will be a great help Mr Ankith

Comment: I have edited the answer.

Comment: Mr Ankith, I think we do not need a model. In the Upload success page we can get the image full pathlike this full_path: C:/xampp/htdocs/Test/uploads/14142053_285506225162220_7595208677878298887_n.jpg, So Isn't that easy to show this path in a <img> tag?

Comment: yes you can do that, I give a solution for may be you want to save it for future reference,